# Why does my animation doesn't work on my css?

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I have a little problem and I need a second eye on it, here is it:
I created an animation for bar progression but seems it's doesn't work and I can't figure why

```css
.prog {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.loading_container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #9985FB;
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #9985FB;
}
.progess_bar {
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: progress_bar 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes progress_bar {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="prog loading_container">
  <div class="prog progress_bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out where is the problem all attributes seems fine and every bracket is open and closed.
Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet,

- `.progess_bar`

should be:

- `.progress_bar`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.prog {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.loading_container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #9985FB;
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #9985FB;
}
.progress_bar {
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: progress_bar 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes progress_bar {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="prog loading_container">
  <div class="prog progress_bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused **by a simple typographical error.** " https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic